# AWS Ubuntu web server can't recognize .do file

Tags: jsp, model-view-controller

When I test on localhost, the page is running normally
but page is placed on a server, It doesn't work
As I tested, jsp files are normally accessed and do not recognize about .do file. When I think, maybe this problem is servlet mapping or tomcat configuration.

I refreshing that but.. still don't work
help me please.

Develope enviroment

- local : JDK8, Tomcat8
- server : JDK8, Tomcat8

[image]

Comment: What is enter image description here supposed to tell us?

Comment: when I try to enter a .do page I got that message and under the message is here

Comment: ... org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:345)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 question.controller.Controller.requestPro(Controller.java:117)
 question.controller.Controller.doGet(Controller.java:89)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)